# understanding matplotlib.subplots python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have constructed a set of pie charts with some help [Insert image into pie chart slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44528024/insert-image-into-pie-chart-slice) 
My charts look wonderful, now I need to place all 6 of them in a 2x3 figure with common tick marks on the shared x and y axis.
For starting I am looking at subplots and thought I could get it to work. I downloaded some examples and started to try a few things.

```
    f, (a) = (plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True))#,
                 #squeeze=False, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None))
    print(type(f),'\n',type(a),'\n')#,type(b))
```

yields:

class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'

class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'

while:

```
    f, (a) = (plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True, squeeze=False, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None))
    print(type(f),'\n',type(a),'\n')#,type(b))
```

returns:

class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'

class 'numpy.ndarray'

When I do this:

```
f, (a,b) = (plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True, squeeze=False, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None))
    print(type(f),'\n',type(a),'\n',type(b))
```

I get the similar results, however if nrows=1 and ncols=2 I get an error:

```
    f, (a,b) = (plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True, squeeze=False, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None))
    print(type(f),'\n',type(a),'\n',type(b))
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

but again this:

```
    f, (a , b) = (
    plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True))#,
                 #squeeze=False, subplot_kw=None, gridspec_kw=None))
    print(type(f),'\n',type(a),'\n',type(b))
```

gives
class 'matplotlib.figure.Figure'

class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'

class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'

Why is it either or array or axes, and also why does a 2X1 work and a 1X2 does not?
I wish to high heaven I could better understand the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The different return types are due to the `squeeze` keyword argument to [`plt.subplots()`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) which is set to `True` by default.
Let's enhance the documentation with the respective unpackings:

> squeeze : bool, optional, default: True
>
> - If True, extra dimensions are squeezed out from the returned Axes object:
>
>   - if only one subplot is constructed (nrows=ncols=1), the resulting single Axes object is returned as a scalar.
>            `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`
>   - for Nx1 or 1xN subplots, the returned object is a 1D numpy object array of Axes objects are returned as numpy 1D arrays.
>       `fig, (ax1, ..., axN) = plt.subplots(nrows=N, ncols=1)` (for Nx1)
>       `fig, (ax1, ..., axN) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=N)` (for 1xN)
>   - for NxM, subplots with N>1 and M>1 are returned as a 2D arrays.
>       `fig, ((ax11, .., ax1M),..,(axN1, .., axNM)) = plt.subplots(nrows=N, ncols=M)`
> - If False, no squeezing at all is done: the returned Axes object is always a 2D array containing Axes instances, even if it ends up being 1x1.
>     `fig, ((ax,),) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, squeeze=False)`
>     `fig, ((ax,), .. ,(axN,)) = plt.subplots(nrows=N, ncols=1, squeeze=False)` for Nx1
>     `fig, ((ax, .. ,axN),) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=N, squeeze=False)` for 1xN
>     `fig, ((ax11, .., ax1M),..,(axN1, .., axNM)) = plt.subplots(nrows=N, ncols=M)`

Alternatively you may always use the unpacked version

```
fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(nrows=N, ncols=M, squeeze=False)
```

and index the array to obtain the axes, `ax_arr[1,2].plot(..)`.

So for a 2 x 3 grid it wouldn't actually matter if you set `squeeze` to `False`. The result will always be a  2D array. You may unpack it as

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3),(ax4, ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
```

to have `ax{i}` as the matplotlib axes objects, or you may use the packed version

```
fig, ax_arr = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)
ax_arr[0,0].plot(..) # plot to first top left axes
ax_arr[1,2].plot(..) # plot to last bottom right axes
```