# what does axes.flat in matplotlib do?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have seen various programs using matplotlib that uses the axes.flat function, like this code:

```
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
```

what does this do?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Let's look a minimal example, where we create some axes with [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598708/understanding-matplotlib-subplots-python),

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
    ax.scatter([i//2+1, i],[i,i//3])
    
plt.show()
```

Here, `axes` is a numpy array of axes,

```
print(type(axes))
> <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(axes.shape)
> (3L, 2L)
```

`axes.flat` is not a function, it's an attribute of the `numpy.ndarray`: [`numpy.ndarray.flat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flat.html)

> `ndarray.flat`
> A 1-D iterator over the array.
> This is a numpy.flatiter instance, which acts similarly to, but is not a subclass of, Python’s built-in iterator object.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,3],
              [4,5],
              [6,7]])
    
for i in a.flat:
    print(i)
```

which would print the numbers `2 3 4 5 6 7`.

Being an interator over the array, you can use it to loop over all the axes from the 3x2 array of axes,

```
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flat):
```

For each iteration it would yield the next axes from that array, such that you may easily plot to all axes in a single loop.

An alternative would be to use `axes.flatten()`, where `flatten()` is method of the numpy array. Instead of an iterator, it returns a flattened version of the array:

```
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
```

There is no difference seen from the outside between the two. However an iterator does not actually create a new array and may hence be slightly faster (although this will never be noticable in the case of matplotlib axes objects).

```
flat1 = [ax for ax in axes.flat]
flat2 = axes.flatten()
print(flat1 == flat2)
> [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

Iterating a flattened version of the axes  array has the advantage that you will save one loop, compared to the naive approach of iterating over rows and columns separately,

```
for row in axes:
    for ax in row:
        ax.scatter(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 3, figsize=())
ax = ax.flatten()
for i, col in enumerate(columns):
    sns.distplot(d2[col], ax=ax[i])
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Please add some explanation too.