# How to use for loop to plot in subplots in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, zip, subplot

Example Input Data:

[image: Image of example input data]

I am a beginner in python. I use for loop to read several csv files look like above(all of those file are same format).

so far my code was look like below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

ax, fig = plt.subplots(4,4,sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(22, 10), dpi=70, linewidth=0.5)
ax = np.array(ax)

def loop_directory(directory):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            file_directory = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            # print(filename)
            df = pd.read_csv(file_directory)

            df = df[df['Tavg'].isin([-999]) == False]

            df[['Year','Month']] = df[['Year','Month']].astype(int).astype(str)
            df["Year&Month"] = df[['Year', 'Month']].agg("/".join,axis=1)

            df["Year&Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Year&Month"])
            x = df["Year&Month"]
            y = df["Tavg"]

            for axes,col in zip(x, y):
                axes.plot(df.index, df[col]) # here is the problem, i dont know how to use for loop to plot in subplots
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   loop_directory(r"C:\Users\LAB312\Desktop\vietnam\anomaly")
```

I've tried for ten more times but didn't work at all.

I want to know how to use those syntaxes ex. ax zip ,etc.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqZ42.png)

I want to plot in every subplot in one plot.
it should have plot every ax.

Comment: Separate the code for data collection code and plotting code.

Once you collect the data, use plt subplots or refer to matplotlib examples.

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Have you checked the matplotlib documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have your `fig` and `ax` reversed in your call to `plt.subplots`, it should be:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4,4,sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(22, 10), dpi=70, linewidth=0.5)
```

You can then access each set of axes to call `plot` by indexing. You can index the 4 by 4 numpy array to get each axes set in your 4 by 4 grid of plots. i.e. `ax[0, 0].plot(...)`, `ax[0, 1].plot(...)`, etc. up to `ax[3, 3].plot(...)`

Your question needs a bit more information to clarify how you want the data plotted though! I can see you combine the first two columns so that you have 4 columns, but consider how do you want each sample to be plotted.

---

EDIT: As you want to plot your files sequentially in `ax[0, 0]`, `ax[0, 1]`, etc., you can [flatten the 2D numpy array of axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46862861/what-does-axes-flat-in-matplotlib-do) to get a 1D iterable that you can loop through or index with one value. I don't have your files so I can't test it but here's some demo code that should give you an idea of what to do.

As @sam mentioned in the comments, you should seperate your csv collection logic and your plotting logic.

```py
def loop_directory(directory):
    # Get all files, filter for '.csv' and prepend dir path
    files = os.listdir(directory)
    csvs = [os.path.join(directory, f) for f in files if f.endswith('.csv')]
    return csvs

def plot_csvs(csvs):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 4, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(22, 10), dpi=70, linewidth=0.5)
    ax = np.array(ax).flatten()  # Flatten to 1D, [0 ,0], [0, 1], etc

    # This assumes number of subplots >= number of CSVs
    for i, filename in enumerate(csvs):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename)

        # Do your processing here

        x = df["Year&Month"]
        y = df["Tavg"]

        ax[i].plot(x, y)

    plt.show()
    
csv_dir = '/path/to/csv/dir'
csv_paths = loop_directory(csv_dir)
plot_csvs(csv_paths)
```

Comment: I've shown what kind of plot i want in the newest edition. Could you check it thank you.

Comment: @9S47L852 sorry, can you be a bit more specific? In your 4x4 grid, what do you want in each plot? I'm assuming you want each column vs year&month (i.e., Precip vs year, Tmin vs year, Tmax vs year, and Tavg vs year) but that only needs 4 plots. What do you want to do with the other 12 subplots?

Comment: because I've 15 csv files in that folder, and each file have the same column such as Tmax Tmin Tavg Year Month Precip, but I only need Year and Tavg. I want 15 csv file s that can plot in to 15 subplots with  x axis and y axis will be Year and Tavg,  respectively.

Comment: Does the order matter?

Comment: Yes, I want the first plot in ax[0, 0] and the second plot ax[0, 1], etc.

Comment: Ok, this is all stuff you should mention in your question ;) let me edit the answer

Comment: thank you so much, I was very confuse about it so that made my question not so clear. Sorry

Comment: No problem. It's good to try and work out what you want beforehand though! See if the new edit gives you an idea of how to solve your issue.

Comment: I try it today, it's work, really thank you so much

Comment: Great! If it works for you, feel free to accept the answer =)